# Horrific Squealing on Start - 2002 Pathfinder

Tags: nissan, troubleshooting, noise, pathfinder

When the engine is cold, horrific squealing comes out from the engine compartment. Horrific squealing remains when the transmission is in park and reverse position. It disappears after driving forward for about 5 to 10 seconds. After this, the engine runs perfectly until next time when it is cold and restarted. However, there is no squealing sound in raining days or when the air is wet (regardless the engine is cold or hot).

Dealer was not able to help because they cannot hear the horrific squealing (because the engine is hot every time I visited the shop).

What could be causing this sound?

What would I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Check the tension on the serpentine belts at the front of the engine - sounds like they're a tad loose. It may be something else, but start there.

Comment: Or the belt is worn out.

Comment: Yup, definitely squealing belts. The belts are slipping either against the A/C compressor or against the alternator.  As they slip a bit they get hot, and when they get hot they don't slip anymore.  They may well be worn or dirty or just old and cracked.   When you have the belts off for inspection and cleaning or replacement, make sure all the pulleys spin freely (air conditioning, idler, alternator and water pump)  If one of those has excessive force that can be a concern.